# Is internal TestFlight testing considered Production (for push)?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, testflight

I am using Apple's HTTP/2 push endpoints and receiving the `DeviceTokenNotForTopic` error when attempting to send push notifications to a test device provisioned via TestFlight.

I have ***absolutely*** verified (about 10x now...) that my `Bundle ID` matches that on the Push Certificate from `developers.apple.com`.

For the HTTP/2 endpoints, there is only one certificate ... I've tried sending to both the `development` and `production` HTTP/2 endpoints.

The ***only*** thing I can think of is that there is some strange mismatch somewhere.  I noticed that, in Xcode, my entitlements file says `APS Environment: development` --- but, when I try to manually change this to `production`, I get an error.

Anyways, when installed via TestFlight, is an app considered "in production" for the sake of push notifications?  Any thoughts or insights are welcomed.  I'd really prefer not to have to rebuild my app...